# How to get the type of an element from range of numbers in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

How to get the type of input data from a range of numbers, combining it with an Enum in c#?
I want to avoid using the if/else, moving it to some kind of range, maybe with using IsDefined?

```
    [Flags]
    public enum PaymentCodeTypes
    {
        Other = 1,
        Warranty = 2,
        Contract = 4
    }
         var PaymentCodeType = 0;
            if (paymentCode >= 80 && paymentCode <= 89)
            {
                PaymentCodeType = (int) PaymentCodeTypes.Contract;
            }
            else if (paymentCode >= 90 && paymentCode <= 99)
            {
                PaymentCodeType = (int) PaymentCodeTypes.Warranty;
            } else
            {
                PaymentCodeType = (int)PaymentCodeTypes.Other;
            }
```

Comment: You could create an attribute with the upper and lower ranges for the payment code value, although in the end it would be about as verbose as what you have here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`switch` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), added in C# 8:

```
var PaymentCodeType = (int)(paymentCode switch {
    var x when x >= 80 && x <= 89 => PaymentCodeTypes.Contract,
    var x when x >= 90 && x <= 99 => PaymentCodeTypes.Warranty,
    _ => PaymentCodeTypes.Other
});
```

If you want to make it even shorter, sacrificing maintainability:

```
var PaymentCodeType = (int)((paymentCode / 10) switch { // only works for ranges in the form of 10x ~ (10x + 9)
    8 => PaymentCodeTypes.Contract,
    9 => PaymentCodeTypes.Warranty,
    _ => PaymentCodeTypes.Other
});
```

Comment: nice idea! but unfortunately I got an error that recursive patterns are not available in c# 7.3, only if upgrade to 8.0 :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. You can change the ranges without changing code and would be more compliant with SOLID principles.

```
        [Flags]
        public enum PaymentCodeTypes
        {
            Other = 1,
            Warranty = 2,
            Contract = 4
        }

        private class Range {
            public Range(int highEnd, int lowEnd, PaymentCodeTypes paymentCodeType)
            {
                this.highEnd = highEnd;
                this.lowEnd = lowEnd;
                this.paymentCodeType = paymentCodeType;
            }
            public int lowEnd { get; private set; }
            public int highEnd { get; private set; }
            public PaymentCodeTypes paymentCodeType { get; private set; }
        }

        private readonly List<Range> paymentCodeRanges = new List<Range>
        {
             new Range(0, 79, PaymentCodeTypes.Other),
             new Range(80, 89,  PaymentCodeTypes.Contract),
             new Range(90, 99, PaymentCodeTypes.Warranty),
             new Range(100, Int32.MaxValue, PaymentCodeTypes.Other )
        };      

        public int SetPaymentTypeCode(int paymentCode)
        {
            var range = paymentCodeRanges.Where(x => paymentCode >= x.lowEnd && paymentCode <= x.highEnd).First();
            return (int)range.paymentCodeType;
        }
```